# psql: no relations found despite existing relations

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema, psql

Version 8.4.16 (no choice in version).

I log into my db as follows:

```
psql -d JRuser
```

The resulting prompt is:

```
JRuser=>
```

I do \d or \dt expecting to see a list of all the relations in schema 'translate'

```
No relations found.
```

But I can select from any of the tables in the schema without any issues.  For example:

```
select * from translate.storage; --works fine
```

I have ensured that the access privileges are correct for JRuser by doing \dn+:

```
                                 List of schemas
        Name        |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |           Description  
translate           | JRuser   | JRuser=UC/JRuser     | 
                               : postgres=UC/JRuser
```

Why can't I see the tables in the translate schema?

Comment: I think you need to use `\dt translation.*`

Comment: I can certainly do that but up until today I've been able to do just \d or \d without any qualifier.  I didn't change any configuration settings so I am puzzled.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\d` in psql only shows *visible* tables, i.e. in your `search_path`.

Try and see:

```
SHOW search_path;
SET search_path= translate;
\d
```

The setting for your session has probably been changed somehow. There are multiple ways to do that:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777)

Related later question on dba.SE:

- [Why can't I see my table (PostgreSQL) when I use \dt(+) inside psql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/110550/3684)

Comment: Can a search_path variable contain multiple schemas if a user wants to be able to show tables on all schemas?

Comment: @lostinthebits: see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-set.html#AEN65998

Comment: Changing the search_path is tedious but necessary for the shell commands to find relations of a new database.  Here's a more detailed answer on what the value of the path needs to be:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777