# Switching Django App Back to PostgreSQL, No Relations Found

Tags: django, postgresql

I switched to my database engine to PostGIS and now I'm switching back to PostgreSQL (so I can continue to use Heroku for free). I changed my settings.py file back to:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'chishenma',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}
```

and commented out the installed app so now it shows:

```
# 'django.contrib.gis',
```

First I made sure that Postgres.app is running. Then I deleted my migrations, ran python manage.py syncdb, and did the South migrations again, all without errors. When I go into the psql shell and type \l, I can see my database, "chishenma," in the list:

```
                                                   List of databases
          Name           |      Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |          Access privileges          
-------------------------+-----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+----------------------
 chishenma               | michelleglauser | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

However, when I type \d, I get "No relations found." I tried to re-create the database, but I get "ERROR: Database chishenma already exists."

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578077/psql-no-relations-found-despite-existing-relations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758533/postgresql-database-owner-cant-access-database-no-relations-found) Stack Overflow thread and determined that my access privileges (I've got the "=UC/postgres" part) and search_path are correct. I get:

```
                                    List of schemas
  Name  |      Owner      |         Access privileges          |      Description       
--------+-----------------+------------------------------------+------------------------
 public | michelleglauser | michelleglauser=UC/michelleglauser+| standard public schema
        |                 | =UC/michelleglauser
```

and:

```
                                List of roles
    Role name    |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 michelleglauser | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
```

What am I missing? How do I make the relations findable?

Comment: The only solution I could find was to start over with a new database.